# Singleton pause before method is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods, singleton

I have created a data controller singleton to have all the networking within my application. It works, but when ever I called a method within the singleton, there is a slight pause before it is executed. Why is this?

View Controller:

```
dataController = [FCDataController sharedInstance];
[dataController refreshData:self];
```

Singleton:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {

    static FCDataController *dataController = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dataController = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return dataController;
}


- (void)refreshData:(id)object {

    // Set the delegate
    [self setDelegate:object];

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(refreshDataDidStart)]) {
        [delegate refreshDataDidStart];
    }

    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[FCDataController parserURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {

            NSLog(@"Reachable");

            NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[FCDataController parserURL]];
            [parser setDelegate:self];
            [parser parse];

            NSLog(@"Refresh Finished");
        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
            NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);


            NSLog(@"Refresh Finished");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: There's a slight pause when you make a network request because network activity is inherently slow. If it's happening at other times, please be more descriptive and try to narrow down the line or _few_ lines of code that seem to be causing the trouble.

Comment: That's not it. The delegate method refreshDidStart does not get called till a couple seconds after the method refreshData is called.

Comment: So, like I said: please be more descriptive. How are you determining the timing, for instance?

Comment: In my view controller where refreshDataDidStart is called, I show the network activity indicator. The indicator does not start animating till like 2 seconds after refreshData is called.

Comment: That isn't definitive evidence, consider adding logging to trace your code rather than relying on UI (particularly when the UI code is outside of your control).